Scrapy-Splash TypeError: name must be an instance of str on crawler.py defer.py
I'm trying to create a Scrapy tool that allows you to select a city to scrape, and it redirects the data to the respective MongoDB database and collection. However, I'm encountering the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:mia\venv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 160, in crawl
yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
TypeError: name must be an instance of str
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:mia\venv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\defer.py", line 348, in maybeDeferred_coro
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "C:mia\venv\Lib\site-packages\pydispatch\robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "C:mia\venv\Lib\site-packages\scrapy\extensions\corestats.py", line 30, in spider_closed
    elapsed_time = finish_time - self.start_time
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType

The error seems to suggest that the name parameter is not being recognized as a string. I have configured my spider as follows:`
Spider (loco.py):
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class LocoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'loco'

    transacciones = ["venta"]
    sectores_a_scrapear = ['bogota', 'antioquia', 'cucuta', 'medellin']
    tipo_inmueble = ['apartamento', 'casa', 'local', 'lote', 'bodega', 'parqueadero']
    
    coneccion = {
        'bogota': ['apartamento_venta', 'casa_venta', 'lote_venta', 'bodega_venta'],
        'medellin': ['apartamento_venta', 'casa_venta', 'lote_venta', 'bodega_venta'],
        'cucuta': ['apartamento_venta', 'casa_venta', 'lote_venta', 'bodega_venta']
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LocoSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.transaccion = input('Ingrese la transaccion: ').strip().lower()
        if self.transaccion not in self.transacciones:
            raise ValueError(f'Transaccion no válida. Debe ser una de {self.transacciones}')
        
        self.sector = input('Ingrese la ciudad a scrapear: ').strip().lower()
        if self.sector not in self.sectores_a_scrapear:
            raise ValueError(f'Ciudad no válida. Debe ser una de {self.sectores_a_scrapear}')
        
        self.tipo = input('Ingrese el tipo de inmueble: ').strip().lower()
        if self.tipo not in self.tipo_inmueble:
            raise ValueError(f'Tipo de inmueble no válido. Debe ser uno de {self.tipo_inmueble}')
        
        self.trans_completa = f"{self.tipo}_{self.transaccion}"
       
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(LocoSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        sector = spider.sector
        if sector in spider.coneccion.keys():
            spider.crawler.settings.set('MONGODB_DATABASE', sector)
        return spider
`
 



Settings (settings.py):
`MONGODB_URI = os.getenv('MONGODB_URI')
MONGODB_DATABASE = 'default_db'
BOT_NAME = "inmueble"
MONGO_CONECCION = {
    'quito': {
        'apartamento_venta': 'apartamento_venta',
        'casa_venta': 'casa_venta',
        'lote_venta': 'lote_venta',
        'bodega_venta': 'bodega_venta'
    },
    'guayaquil': {
        'apartamento_venta': 'apartamento_venta',
        'casa_venta': 'casa_venta',
        'lote_venta': 'lote_venta',
        'bodega_venta': 'bodega_venta'
    },
    'cuenca': {
        'apartamento_venta': 'apartamento_venta',
        'casa_venta': 'casa_venta',
        'lote_venta': 'lote_venta',
        'bodega_venta': 'bodega_venta'
    }
}

Pipeline (pipelines.py):

import pymongo
import logging

class MongoDBPipeline:
    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db, coneccion):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db
        self.coneccion = coneccion
        self.client = MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = None

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        settings = crawler.settings
        mongo_uri = settings.get('MONGO_URI')
        mongo_db = settings.get('MONGO_DB')
        coneccion = settings.get('MONGO_CONECCION')
        return cls(mongo_uri, mongo_db, coneccion)

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        try:
            self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
            self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'Error connecting to MongoDB: {e}')
            raise

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        if self.client:
            self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        city = spider.sector
        trasaction_type = spider.trans_completa
        collection_name = self.coneccion.get(city, {}).get(trasaction_type)
        print(collection_name, " y su tipo es:", type(collection_name))
        if collection_name:
            collection = self.db[collection_name]
            collection.insert_one(dict(item))
        else:
            logging.warning(f'No collection found for city: {city}, type: {trasaction_type}')

        return item

I only want to know, whats the meaning of this error, it may be at the connection with mongo, at managing the collection names, but that error does not point this library...

how do you run the spider when you encountered the error?

i run it like:
scrapy crawl loco

This question is similar to: PyMongo - Name must be an instance of Str. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
